# Where do you store global settings/variables in concrete5?

Tags: concrete5-5.7

In a concrete5 website, where is the best place to store global variables that you would like to access site-wide across templates and controllers etc.?

e.g. A specific external URL, a Facebook ID, some kind of version number, etc.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do this in code (as opposed to via the CMS), you can put this in `application/config/app.php`:

```
<?php
return [
    'FacebookAppId' => '1234',
];
```

And then in controllers/templates you can retrieve it via:

```
<?= Config::get('app.FacebookAppId') ?>
```